# How can I generate multiple HTML files from one .md file or add external HTML, CSS for view?

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll, liquid

- Is it possible to generate let's say, two files (index1.html and
  index2.html) from one markdown file (index.md)?
- Or can I add HTML, CSS only for viewing the HTML files in my Browser
  (don't want to use a browser plugin)?

I want to use Jekyll to generate .html snippets, which can be stored on AWS S3 and included on my website. For that purpose I don't need HTML tags like `<DOCTYPE>`, `<head>`, `<footer>` etc. because they are already on my website. But I require them to view the final .html document in my browser.

Some other ideas I thought about but also couldn't find a solution:

- add a second .md file and include index.md, so the content is the
  same
- duplicate the index.html file and strip head, footer ... with another
  program

I couldn't find any solution anywhere, but it can't be, that I'm the only person having this problem. I also couldn't find a Plugin to resolve that issue.

Edit:
At the moment I get this .html when I run `bundle exec jekyll serve`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/styles.css" />
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
       my_body_content
    <footer>
      
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

but I only want the .html file to contain this:

```
       my_body_content
```

But of course when I try to view this .html file in my Browser for editing purposes no styling is applied.
But I require a styling to view the file in my Browser verify that content of the .html file is rendered correctly before uploading it to S3 and fetching it on my website where my website styling will be applied.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're trying to do. Something like `_include`, but hosted on an S3 server? Can you add a minimal example of input and expected output?

Comment: This might be too limiting for you, but my new open source project https://Docsify-This.net lets you create and style simple web pages from one or more Markdown files.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I'm using smarty fetch to retrieve the .html files from S3 and display them. 
Example code: `{{fetch file='https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com/xxx/index.html'}}`
This part already works.

Comment: I don't know smarty fetch, but doesn't that interfere with Liquid templates? Or should it be `{% ... %}`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. It works, so I don't think that it interfere. But that's not the problem either. 
My Problem is that I don't know how to generate two templates.